# Cardinality of Cartesian Product of Uncountable Set with Countable Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is it true that if $I$ is an infinite set, then $I\times \mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $I$? I believe it, but I have minimal background in set theory. My guess is that we can construct an injection from $I\times \mathbb{N}$ to $I,$ but I don't see an obvious way to do so.

Comment: For infinite cardinals $\kappa,\lambda$, $\kappa\cdot \lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}$.

Comment: and what is the explicit bijection?

Comment: The result is true, but it is not obvious, since it requires some amount of the axiom of choice. In some specific cases, the existence of these injections can be established directly, of course (for example, if $I=\mathbb N$, or $\mathbb R$).

Comment: thanks - would you be able to provide an argument, or does it require some extra background?

Comment: One way (that requires some understanding of ordinals) is to well-order $I$, say in type a limit ordinal $\kappa$. Now, use an explicit bijection from $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, to map $\kappa\times\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ by mapping each $\omega$-block $[\omega\alpha,\omega(\alpha+1))\times\omega$ to $[\omega\alpha,\omega(\alpha+1))$.

Comment: unfortunately I don't know anything about ordinals. i suppose now is a good a time as any to start reading up on set theory. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the equality of cardinals $\alpha \cdot \beta = \max\{\alpha,\beta\}$ holds when at least one of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is an infinite cardinal. In particular, if $I$ is infinite with cardinality $\alpha$, then $|I\times\Bbb N| = \alpha\cdot\aleph_0 = \max\{\alpha,\aleph_0\} = \alpha$.

The proofs I've seen of $\alpha \cdot \beta = \max\{\alpha,\beta\}$ all go through the simpler-looking special case $\alpha \cdot \alpha = \alpha$ (again for $\alpha$ infinite). Unfortunately, I don't know a proof of this special case that avoids well-ordering and ordinals, although it's still simpler to prove since one can use transfinite induction on $\alpha$. Fortunately, the derivation of the full case from this special case is easy: if $\alpha > \beta > 1$ then $\alpha \le \alpha + \beta \le \alpha + \alpha = \alpha\cdot2 \le \alpha\cdot\beta \le \alpha\cdot\alpha = \alpha$ (where all inequalities follow easily from definitions); hence we must have $\alpha\cdot\beta=\alpha$.